# Migrating from XWIKI to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, migration, data

Is there a way to migrate pages from XWiki 6.4.4 to Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not out of box, you have to use the 3rd party tools to migrate from xwiki to SharePoint. I think check with metalogix they have strong wording on wiki transfer. you can test that tool as they offer trial.

You can also check http://inkchilli.com/.

Other way is manually move the data.